# WCF Service Library

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF services. I was asked to manually create a WCF service. I did the following:

1. Created a new project Console App.
2. Created a class called `Evaluation`
3. Created an interface called `IEvaluatorService`
4. Created a class `EvaluationService` implementing the interface `IEvaluatorService`

I need to use the following address: `http://localhost:8000/Evaluations` then test my service via WcfTestClient. I am not sure what to do next. Code below.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
namespace Evaluations
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IEvaluatorService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name="AddEvaluation")]
        int Add(string user, string content);

        [OperationContract(Name="RemoveEvaluation")]
        void Remove([MessageParameter(Name="existingID")] int id);

        [OperationContract(Name="GetAllEvaluations")]
        Evaluation[] GetAll();

        [OperationContract(Name="GetEvaluation")]
        Evaluation Get(int id);

        [OperationContract(Name="GetAllEvaluationsFrom")]
        Evaluation[] GetAll([MessageParameter(Name = "username")] string submitter);
    }
}

namespace Evaluations
{
    class EvaluationService : IEvaluatorService
    {
        List<Evaluation> myList = new List<Evaluation>();
        static int count = 0;

        public int Add(string user, string content)
        {
            Evaluation eval = new Evaluation()
            {
                UniqueID = count++, 
                Submitter = user,
                SubmissionTime = DateTime.Now,
                Text = content
            };
            myList.Add(eval);
            return eval.UniqueID;
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            myList.RemoveAt(id);
        }

        public Evaluation[] GetAll()
        {
            return myList.ToArray<Evaluation>();
        }

        public Evaluation Get(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Evaluation[] GetAll(string submitter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace Evaluations
{
    [DataContract]
    class Evaluation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Submitter { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int UniqueID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime SubmissionTime { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is...

- go into Visual Studio
- right click on your project
- select Add New
- choose WCF Service

See what code Visual Studio added and follow that pattern for your service.